# Detekt. Different thresholds for same rule

Tags: kotlin, detekt

I'm using Detekt and I need to configure LargeClass rule. I want to set different thresholds for production and test classes. Is it possible to configure it such way?

Answer (score 0):

Finally I found solution.
I was able to achieve this by creating separate yaml file with only specific rule and different threshold for this rule, and pass it with --config, -c flag:

```
gradle detekt -c main.yaml, test.yaml
```